# X509 Certificate Thumbprint

Tags: certificates

Does an issued X509 certificate have a thumbprint (hash) included as one of the items in
the X509 certificate?

Answer (score 2):

No, an X.509 certificate does not include it's own fingerprint.  The X.509 fingerprint values used are a hash of the **entire** certificate.  For the obvious reason, you can't include the result of a hash operation into the source of the hashed data without invalidating the hash.

Other fingerprints may be included in the certificate; see [What is the actual value of a certificate fingerprint](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/what-is-the-actual-value-of-a-certificate-fingerprint) for a good answer on this topic.